# com.google.android.youtube.player.youtubeplayerview modestbranding is disabled or hide in android

Tags: android-studio

google youtube player using

```
@Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider arg0, YouTubePlayer player,
            boolean restored) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        player.setFullscreenControlFlags(YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CONTROL_ORIENTATION);

        //This flag tells the player to automatically enter fullscreen when in landscape. Since we don't have
        //landscape layout for this activity, this is a good way to allow the user rotate the video player.
        player.addFullscreenControlFlag(YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_ALWAYS_FULLSCREEN_IN_LANDSCAPE);

        if(!restored){    //lnIEn0kWdhY
            player.cueVideo(getIntent().getStringExtra("VIDEO_ID"));
            //player.cueVideo("lnIEn0kWdhY");    
            //player.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT);
        }
        else {
            Log.e("dd","dff");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the minimal video player style to hide the youtube icon. But it will show only timer bar play/pause controls.

```
player.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.MINIMAL);
```

Comment: Do we have an opportunity to customize play/pause controls with com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer ?